# How to get capacity of a deque?

Tags: c++, deque

So I recently covered deques and I was wondering, are there any ways to access the `capacity()` of a `std::deque` such as we do it on a `std::vector`?

I found this member function `std::deque::max_size` however this represents:

> The maximum number of elements a deque container can hold as content.

and does not correspond to what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you know why a `std::list` has no capacity? The reason is the same for a `deque`

Comment: @idclev463035818 no I didn't cover `std::list` yet, but nothing was mentionned about that on deques

Comment: "and does not correspond to what I want." what do you actually want? This is a mild form of a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us why you think you need to know the capacity of a deque then maybe we can explain you that you don't need it

Comment: the same thing that the `std::vector::capacity()` returns @idclev463035818 . Max_size returns for me a huge number on a deque.

Comment: but a deque is not a vector, so there is no "same thing"

Comment: @idclev463035818 I though the only difference between a deque and a vector was that I could insert/remove elements in the beginning, I didn't know it stored elements in non-contiguous memory.

Comment: @Alex: You can `insert/erase` elements anywhere in a `vector` too. It just won't be *fast*, which is why it doesn't have `push/pop_front` functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas indeed, strange that the non-contiguous part wasn't mentioned in my book though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A double-ended queue (std::deque) doesn't have a capacity. It is because when adding new elements, it allocates more memory, unlike std::vector, which allocates some memory, and when it's full, it moves all elements to a new location.

This means that the memory isn't contigous, unlike in std::vector. max_size is the theoretical limit on the number of elements, which is usually far bigger then your actual needs.

Comment: That's not really true. "because when adding new elements, it allocates more memory" is an incorrect statement. Deque does not have to allocate memory on **each** element added.

Comment: But if it's true it implies that it does have a capacity, because if it allocates memory for example for 3 elements, then after addition, it would leave us with a capacity of 2. Of course it would need to be a capacity_back and a capacity_front, but still, it should have it then

Comment: Perhaps it should. This is why I maintain the answer is incorrect.

Comment: a `std::deque` has capacity. For example there is `deque::shrink_to_fit`